# Samsung drives not detected through adapter

Tags: hard-drive, sata, sata-to-usb

I've got a strange case that I just can't wrap my head around.

I had 4 internal HDDs in my pc, 1 Seagate, 1 Toshiba and 2 Samsungs. I wanted to start using these drives as externals (to use with a Raspberry Pi), so I bought 4 3.5" SATA enclosures.

There were no problems at all with the Seagate and the Toshiba, but the Samsungs are doing my nut in.

Both of them work fine internally, but are not detected through the enclosure. Not by windows file explorer, disk management, or the RaspPi.

I've got no clue at all how to make this work, especially as the drive work fine when internally connected.

Who is going to save my day (or week by now)?:)

Comment: Size of the Samsung drive?

Comment: Try a Newer adapter, depending on the sata to usb Chip in the adapter it may not recognize the size of the drive it does not attach to the drive.

Comment: Both 2TBs, as were the Seagate and Toshiba for that matter. I'll check if I can find myself a newer enclosure/adapter.

Comment: Model of the Samsung drives?

Comment: Samsung HD203wi and HD204ui. I've found a firmware update for the 204 and installed it, but no luck yet.